# how to set mysql max temporary in memory table size

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I am using a temporary table by using following code:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (ID INT(11), Actress varchar(200)) 
ENGINE=MEMORY
SELECT ID, Actress FROM actress_titles order by id;
```

But I am getting the next error: Error code 1114, the table 'temp' is full.
I have also tried to increase temporary table size by executing following code:

```
SET GLOBAL tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 5;
SET GLOBAL max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 5;
```

But when I read the variable the size is 99999744 bytes

```
(select @@max_heap_table_size;)
```

So, I'm still getting the 1114 error...

How can I increase the max size of temporary tables beyond this 99mb?

Answer (score 4):

The following code must be executed to set the variables:

```
SET @@tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 5;
SET @@max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 5;
```

Comment: Heads up! This will set the tmp_table_size to around 5GB. Double check the numbers to make sure they're right.